# Scala: Ordering contravariance

Tags: scala, generics, types, contravariance, type-systems

Is there any reason why Scala's `Ordering` trait is not contravariant? A motivating example follows.

Suppose I want to perform an ordered insert. I may have a function with the signature

```
def insert[A, B >: A](list: List[A], item: A)(implicit ord: Ordering[B]): List[A]
```

Here, I have an `Ordering` which accepts super types of type `A`. I imagine this is useful when you're dealing with `case classes`. For example:

```
abstract class CodeTree
case class Fork(left: CodeTree, right: CodeTree, chars: List[Char], weight: Int) extends CodeTree
case class Leaf(char: Char, weight: Int) extends CodeTree

def weight(tree: CodeTree): Int 
def chars(tree: CodeTree): List[Char] 

implicit object CodeTreeOrdering extends Ordering[CodeTree] {
  def compare(a: CodeTree, b: CodeTree): Int = weight(a) compare weight(b)
}
```

I would want my insert function to work with types `List[CodeTree]`, `List[Leaf]` or `List[Fork]`. However, as `Ordering` isn't contravariant, I need to define implicit `Orderings` for each `case`.

If I define

```
trait MyOrdering[-A] {
  def compare(a: A, b: A): Int
}
```

everything works as expected.

Is there any other way to achieve my goal?

EDIT:

My current solution is to define insert as

```
def insert[A](list: List[A], item: A)(implicit ord: Ordering[A]): List[A]
```

which works fine when dealing with `List[CodeTree]`. I also define (inspired by the scalaz library):

```
trait Contravariant[F[_]] {
  def contramap[A, B](r: F[A], f: B => A): F[B]
}

implicit object OrderingContravariant extends Contravariant[Ordering] {
  def contramap[A, B](r: Ordering[A], f: B => A) = r.on(f)
}

implicit def orderingCodeTree[A <: CodeTree]: Ordering[A] =
  implicitly[Contravariant[Ordering]].contramap(CodeTreeOrdering, identity)
```

I'm defining an implicit factory function for `Ordering[A <: CodeTree]` instances.

Comment: Looks like it's a bit of a technical issue relating to the type inferencer failing to find the most specific ordering. See http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Contravariant-Ordering-T-java-util-Comparator-and-uncheckedVariance-td1955224.html for details.

Comment: @Impredicative I edited the post with a nasty workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit more of a detailed answer pulled out of the thread on 'scala-language' linked in the comment above.

The reason that `Ordering` is not contravariant is that this doesn't accord sensibly with the notion of specificity used in implicit resolution. Implicit resolution will try to pick the most 'specific' type for a parameter, and considers one type to be more specific than another if it's a subtype of it. This makes sense in covariant cases: I'd rather have an implicit specific to my list of strings than one for any old list. In contravariant cases, however, it wants to pick the wrong thing:

```
trait Ord[-A]
A <: B
Ord[B] <: Ord[A]
```

And so it will pick the 'most specific' ordering as being, if available, `Ordering[Any]`.

There looks to be a [big discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-language/ZE83TvSWpT4) going on changing the way 'specificity' is defined with regard to contravariant parameters on the scala-language group.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. I was hoping my second day with Scala would go smoother!

Answer (score 3):

In the current API, these methods prevent it from being contravariant:

```
  /** Return `x` if `x` >= `y`, otherwise `y`. */
  def max(x: T, y: T): T = if (gteq(x, y)) x else y

  /** Return `x` if `x` <= `y`, otherwise `y`. */
  def min(x: T, y: T): T = if (lteq(x, y)) x else y
```

Comment: It's easy enough to fix `max` and `min` by parametrising over a subtype of `T`, though.

Comment: True -- the most specific argument resolution would be the most accurate answer.